# Pandas date parser sets day to current when missing

Tags: python, pandas

I'm parsing a fixed width file that supplies a month and a year, and i want to create a pandas date from month and year that uses 1 as the day (instead of the current day of the month as Pandas defaults to do).

```
df = pd.read_fwf("/file", colspecs=colspecs,header=None,names=names, 
parse_dates= =  {'calendar':['eligYear',"eligMonth"]},keep_date_col=True)
```

Data example:

```
eligyear eligmonth
2012     02
2012     01
```

Ideal outcome where days = 1 instead of the current day of the month, e.g.

```
calendar
2012-02-01
2012-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can better parse the numbers to a datetime after reading in the csv, this will be more flexible.
You can for example do:

```
In [43]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+')

In [47]: df['calendar'] = pd.to_datetime(df['eligyear']*10000 + df['eligmonth']*100 + 1, format='%Y%m%d')


In [48]: df
Out[48]: 
   eligyear  eligmonth   calendar
0      2012          2 2012-02-01
1      2012          1 2012-01-01
```